# function to be run multiple times to generate the final dataset in R

Tags: r

I am new to R and have written a function that needs to be run multiple times to generate the final dataset.
So the multiple times is determined by the vector of unique years and again based on these years every single time the function gives an output.
Still I am not getting the right output.

Desired output: for eg it takes 10 samples from each year, after 10th run I should have 100 rows of correct output.

```
create_strsample <- function(n1,n2){   
   yr <- c(2010,2011,2012,2013)
   for(i in 1:length(yr)){

     k1<-subset(data,format(as.Date(data$account_opening_date),"%Y")==yr[i])
     r1 <-sample(which(!is.na(k1$account_closing_date)),n1,replace=FALSE)
     r2<-sample(which(is.na(k1$account_closing_date)),n2,replace=FALSE)
     #final.data <-k1[c(r1,r2),]
     sample.data <- lapply(yr, function(x) {f.data<-create_strsample(200,800)})

     k1 <- do.call(rbind,k1)
     return(k1)
   }

   final <- do.call(rbind,sample.data)
   return(final)
}
stratified.sample.data <- create_strsample(200,800)
```

Comment: Well the fact that you're calling `create_strsample` inside the definition of `create_strsample` can't bode well. Also, can you provide a small example dataset, and a sample output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A MWE would have been nice, but I'll give you a template for these kind of questions. Note, that this is not optimized for speed (or anything else), but only for the ease of understanding.

As noted in the comments, that call to `create_strsample` in the loop looks weird and probably isn't what you really want.

```
data <- data.frame()         # we need an empty, but existing variable for the first loop iteration
for (i in 1:10) {    
    temp <- runif(1,max=i)   # do something...
    data <- rbind(data,temp) # ... and add this to 'data'
}                            # repeat 10 times
rm(temp)                     # don't need this anymore
```

That `return(k1)` in the loop also looks wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this later after your suggestion @herbaman for the desired output minus the lapply.

```
create_strsample <- function(n1,n2){
final.data <- NULL
yr <- c(2010,2011,2012,2013)

for(i in 1:length(yr)){

    k1<-subset(data,format(as.Date(data$account_opening_date),"%Y")==yr[i])
    r1 <- k1[sample(which(!is.na(k1$account_closing_date)),n1,replace=FALSE), ]
    r2 <- k1[sample(which(is.na(k1$account_closing_date)),n2,replace=FALSE), ]
    sample.data <- rbind(r1,r2)
    final.data <- rbind(final.data, sample.data)
}

return(final.data)
}


 stratified.sample.data <- create_strsample(200,800)
```